# Exception using nested Input Types in GraphQL and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

I'm trying to create a Mutation that receives an input type like this:

```
input Cart {
    items: [CartItem!]!
    client: String!
}

input CartItem {
    productId: Int!
    qty: Int!
}
```

And my Mutation goes like this:

```
type Mutation {
    createOrder(cart: Cart!): Order!
}
```

But when I try to run my Application I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaError: Expected type 'CartItem' to be a GraphQLOutputType, but it wasn't!  Was a type only permitted for object types incorrectly used as an input type, or vice-versa?
```

What's going on?

Comment: Are you using CartItem anywhere else in your schema, like as part of Order?

Comment: No, just as an input type in this case

Comment: Did you make sure your Cart and CartItem java class have public getters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known bug of Graphql-java-tools: https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-tools/issues/216

The input java types should have public getters.

Answer (score 0):

You should initiate a proper class implementation for their respective graphql schema declaration.

You can check an example here: https://github.com/MerNat/graphql-spring-boot-nested-input-types-example

Comment: Hello! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

except the input java types should have public getters, the input java types should also implement `Serializable` interface

Comment: can you provide the reference for this?